# Lots of functions that take the same parameter?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, facade

Im sorry for if the question is bit unclear. please feel free to clearup/generelize this question. I don't know english well enough to do it myself

I need to use a web service all the methods of the web service take as first parameter an authentication object

```
class webservice{
    e_webservice_return_value method1(object authentication,object param1,object param2,object param32)
    e_webservice_return_value method2(object authentication,object param1,object param2)
    .....
}
```

there are hundreds of methods.

I want to create a provider class that will provide all methodes 
now I can create a class named provider and write for each method

```
class provider{
    object _auth;
    e_webservice_return_value method1(object param1,object param2,object param3)
    {
        var res= method1(_auth,param1,param2,param3);
        if(res=bad auth)
        {
            ReAuth(auth);
        }
        return res;
    }

    e_webservice_return_value method2(object param1,object param2)
    {
        var res =return e_webservice_return_value method2(_auth,param1,param2);
        if(res=bad auth)
        {
            ReAuth(auth);
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

I need this pattern for all the hundreds of methods.

is there a technique to create such a facade object without actually writing 100ds of functions all with same functionality? (only first parameter is the same) others may differ

Comment: Shouldn't you use a delegate and invoke that delegate only when the authentication worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to go with `Reflection.Emit`. A nice, but maybe a bit outdated tutorial, can be found at [this site](http://www.drdobbs.com/generating-code-at-run-time-with-reflect/184416570). Also take a look at MSDN - they have **great** documentation!

What you generally would like to do is to mark each method (or a whole class) with an attribute and for each such a method/class with an attribute create a wrapping method, and replace the code. You could make it run on application initialization or on the first call to this class/method, the design is up to you.

This is no easy task, but actually we had the same case in our project, and it proved to be quite a good solution. That's because each method with a given attribute required a similar handling.

Keep in mind that there are some alternative approaches to code emitting, but I do not know them well, so I cannot provide any suggestions - but it'd be easily googlable.

`Reflection.Emit` with IL by itself is quite troublesome, but certainly it allows you to learn a deal more about what's going on in your c# code, under the hood.

Comment: I understand the idea but that would probably be horrible intelisense wise wouldn't it?

Comment: Oh yes, that's true. Not only from intelisense point of view, the compilation would not know about the new methods either. My suggestion comes from the fact, that you're building a web service. Our scenario is:
take a method, that is a WCF endpoint (with restful API), 
create a wrapper for that method with IL, 
treat this wrapper as a new enpoint.
This way we never call our method directly, they are called by the framework, because they have proper WCF attributes. There are also other scenarios possible, some harder, some easier ;]